# Build an "intelligent" \footcite for Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, programming

I want to build a command similar to `footcite` to be used in `Beamer`. It should work in the following manner:

- If the reference was not used in the current frame, then print a footnote with `fullcite` and the letter as `footmark`.
- If it was already used in the current frame, then just the letter as `footmark`.
- If the reference is again used in another frame, then print a footnote with `fullcite` and the letter as `footmark`.

The MWE below is almost there. But, the problem is that in the first frame, after the first use of `\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}`, it should appear `a` and not `b` as `footmark`; and therefore avoid the warning

> warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
>   (name{3GPP:36.104}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{3GPP:36.104,
    author={3GPP},
    institution={3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP)},
    title={Evolved Universal Terrestrial Radio Access {(E-UTRA)}; Base Station {(BS)} radio transmission and reception},
    type={TS},
    number={36.104},
    year=2012,
    month=sep,
    url={http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/36104.htm},
    urldate={2014-04},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcounter{tmpfootnote}
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\setcounter{symfootnote}{0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfootcite[1]{%
    \unskip%
    \ifcsname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname%
        \textsuperscript{\ref*{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\def\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname{#1}%
        \setcounter{tmpfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thesymfootnote}%
        \footnote{\label{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}\fullcite{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}.}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{symfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thetmpfootnote}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    bla\footnote{Test 1}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\footnote{Test 2}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    bla\footnote{Test 3}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\footnote{Test 4}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just put text bottom of the frame instead of all these ?

Comment: @percusse This is part of the code for a template to be used by others. That is why.

Comment: Maybe tackle the problem from the `biblatex` site? If you look into styles like `authoryear-ibid` they already have mechanism to detect if a reference is used more than once on a single page.

Comment: Can you have a look at http://pastebin.com/sjH8r2mB. Maybe you can do some addtocounter-voodoo at the line with `{already seen}`.

Comment: Do you really believe your audience will follow footnote marks in the slide and be interested in a full reference? I don't think so. Use “author-year” in the text and point to the printed paper for the full references.

Comment: @egreg I believe audience will not follow the references. But when you present to scientific audience, references are useful.

Comment: @samcarter I didn't know about those commands. After some trial and error I could get it to work. But can you provide your answer here?

Comment: @cacamailg Good to hear you found an answer! My code snipped was rather an Ansatz and far from a finished solution, so I think it is not appropriate as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
\newcounter{tmpfootnote}
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\setcounter{symfootnote}{0}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfootcite[1]{%
    \unskip%
    \ifcsname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname%
        \textsuperscript{\ref*{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\def\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname{fnct#1@\theframenumber}%
        \setcounter{tmpfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thesymfootnote}%
        \footnote{\label{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}\fullcite{#1}.}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{symfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thetmpfootnote}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

The full example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{3GPP:36.104,
    author={3GPP},
    institution={3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP)},
    title={Evolved Universal Terrestrial Radio Access {(E-UTRA)}; Base Station {(BS)} radio transmission and reception},
    type={TS},
    number={36.104},
    year=2012,
    month=sep,
    url={http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/36104.htm},
    urldate={2014-04},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcounter{tmpfootnote}
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\setcounter{symfootnote}{0}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfootcite[1]{%
    \unskip%
    \ifcsname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname%
        \textsuperscript{\ref*{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\def\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname{fnct#1@\theframenumber}%
        \setcounter{tmpfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thesymfootnote}%
        \footnote{\label{\csname fnct#1@\theframenumber\endcsname}\fullcite{#1}.}%
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
        \setcounter{symfootnote}{\thefootnote}%
        \setcounter{footnote}{\thetmpfootnote}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    bla\footnote{Test 1}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\footnote{Test 2}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    bla\footnote{Test 3}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\footnote{Test 4}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}

    bla\myfootcite{3GPP:36.104}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```